# getting isEmail of undefined error when creating registration system in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, momentjs

Sorry I'm new to javascript and nodejs, but basically I am trying to create a registration system. I've attached my form validator and my user schema, but I keep getting an isEmail of undefined error. I'm not sure if there's an easier way to go about checking these conditions. Earlier, I was using req.checkBody, but I wasn't sure how to use that to check if a certain user is above a given age.

```
  router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  var name = req.body.name; 
  var email = req.body.email;
  var password = req.body.password; 
  var password2 = req.body.password2; 
  var bday = req.body.bday; 
  var birthday = moment(bday); 
  let errors = []; 

  // Form Validator
  if (!name || !email || !password || !password2 || !bday) {
    errors.push({ msg: 'Please fill in all required fields' }); 
  }

  if (!req.body.email.isEmail()) {
    errors.push({ msg: 'Please provide an appropriate email' }); 
  }  

  if (req.body.password2 != req.body.password) {
    errors.push({ msg: 'Please make sure your passwords match' }); 
  }

  if (!birthday.isValid()) {
    errors.push({ msg: 'Date of Birth must be in appropriate format' }); 
  }

  if (moment().diff(birthday, 'years') < 13) {
    errors.push({ msg: 'User must be at least 13 years of age' }); 
  }
    if(errors.length > 0){
    res.render('register', {
      errors, 
      name, 
      email, 
      password, 
      password2, 
      bday
    });
  } else{
    var newUser = new User({
      name: name,
      email: email,
      password: password,
      bday: bday, 
    });


var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    bday: {
        type: String
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you look at this here

```
  if (!req.body.email.isEmail()) {
    errors.push({ msg: 'Please provide an appropriate email' }); 
  }
```

You are trying to access the `isEmail` properties from `email` which must've been non existent.

What the `req` might have looked like: `{ req: { body: {} } }`, as you can see email must be `undefined` and `undefined` does not contain `isEmail` property.

What you can do is

```
  if (req.body.email && !req.body.email.isEmail()) {
    errors.push({ msg: 'Please provide an appropriate email' }); 
  }
```

Check first if `req.body.email` exists before trying to access `isEmail`.